# How to prevent user selection of axis labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm tuning a highcharts graph and on mobile I touch the graph and slide my finger to see the values across the graph.

The issue comes when I am holding a touch, the nearby text becomes highlighted and when I let go it asks if I want to copy, select all, etc.

Since the nearby text are the labels of the Axis and the series names in the legend, is there a way to disable this text selection functionality while touching inside a highcharts plot?

I've attempted to simply hide the Axis labels using responsive mode as mobile doesn't have room for them anyway, however I'm unable to get this to work for addAxis() and the legend series text still gets selected.

Unfortunately I've not found any examples that are highcharts specific which only apply to the plot/legend area.

I have found similar code in CSS but there are other areas on the page which need to be selected, they just aren't inside the graph.

```
.row-of-icons {
-webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
-moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
-ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
user-select: none;          /* Likely future */      
}
```

I want to be able to touch and hold the graph in highcharts without the "Copy, Share, Select All" overlay appearing.

This occurs on pretty much any mobile device when you press and hold on a text area.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you expect by adding attached CSS rules to the chart container element. Check the code and test it on demo posted below.

**Code:**

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    data: [
      439,
      525,
      571,
      696,
      970,
      119,
      137,
      154
    ]
  }],
});
```

```css
#container {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#footer,
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #555;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

**Demo:**

- code editor: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1ac63t8o/1/
- result (test it on mobile): https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1ac63t8o/1/show